# Problem with SaveChanges() Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: many-to-many, entity-relationship, entity-framework-4.1

I am having problem with saving the changes to database.

I am updating the model A in my controller, however when I save the changes using SaveChanges() I end up having a duplicated item in database for B.

After the UpdateModel() is called I inspected the Bs property and it was as I expected however right after the SaveChanges() is called if I inspect the Bs property I will see that the Id is completely different (new Id and new entry).

My class is similar to this:

```
public class A
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int AId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs{ get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int BId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<A> As{ get; set; }
}
```

My Controller is like this :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(A theA)
    {
        try
        {
           db.Entry(theA).State = EntityState.Modified;

           foreach (var item in theA.Bs)
           {
               db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
           }

           db.SaveChanges();

           return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your controller method would be important to see where you retrieve the objects from DB, modify them and call SaveChanges.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is common behavior. The problem is that EF doesn't know that you attached an existing `B` so it automatically inserts a new record. You must say EF that the `B` is existing one by calling:

```
// here add B to the collection in the A and after that call:
dbContext.Entry<B>(someB).State = EntityState.Unchanged();
```

or by attaching `B` before you add it to collection in `A` (I'm not sure if this is possible when using `UpdateModel` in ASP.NET MVC).

```
dbContext.Bs.Attach(someB);
// now add B to the collection in the A
```

Other possibility is to load `B` from database first and add loaded object to the collection in `A` but it is additional roundtrip to database.

```
int id = someB.Id;
var loadedB = dbCotnext.Bs.Single(b => b.Id == id);
someA.Bs.Add(loadedB);
dbContext.As.Add(someA);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Conclusion: Every time you call `Add` the whole object graph is tracked as inserted unless you attach related entities first (before you add them to inserted parent - the 2nd and 3rd example) or unless you manually change the state of related entities back to unchanged after adding the parent. (the 1st example).

Comment: Thanks,
I tried the first method, however I get the following message as soon as its called:

"AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges."

Comment: So how did you get your B instance and how did you create your context? Is the context instanced per request and is B with given key used only once (single instance) per context?

Comment: I have added my ActionMethod to the Question, can you please take a look ?

Comment: I can now edit without any problem by creating a completely new Context in my action method. Is this correct ? Why can't I keep one context for the whole controller ?

Comment: Have you used your controller context for anything else? Is it per request context or globally shared context?

Comment: Before this fix, I was using one context per controller and this didn't work. Then I created a brand new context for my edit action method (inside the method) then this fixed the problem.

Comment: But one context per controller actually doesn't answer the question. Did you used a new instance of the context for each request?

Comment: @Ladislav yes I used a new instance context for each request.