# Entity Framework: Duplicate Records in Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have following entity framework code first code. The tables are created and data is inserted. However there are duplicate records in Club table.

My operations are:-

1. Create clubs using club creation app
2. Create persons using person app

How to avoid the duplicate entry?

[image]

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<NerdDinners>(new MyInitializer());

        CreateClubs();
        InsertPersons();

    }

    public static void CreateClubs()
    {

        string connectionstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NerdDinners;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        using (var db = new NerdDinners(connectionstring))
        {

            Club club1 = new Club();
            club1.ClubName = "club1";

            Club club2 = new Club();
            club2.ClubName = "club2";

            Club club3 = new Club();
            club3.ClubName = "club3";

            db.Clubs.Add(club1);
            db.Clubs.Add(club2);
            db.Clubs.Add(club3);

            int recordsAffected = db.SaveChanges();


        }
    }

    public static Club GetClubs(string clubName)
    {
        string connectionstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NerdDinners;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        using (var db = new NerdDinners(connectionstring))
        {

            //var query = db.Clubs.Where(p => p.ClubName == clubName);
            var query = db.Clubs.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ClubName == clubName);
            return query;
        }
    }

    public static void InsertPersons()
    {
        string connectionstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NerdDinners;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        using (var db = new NerdDinners(connectionstring))
        {

            Club club1 = GetClubs("club1");
            Club club2 = GetClubs("club2");
            Club club3 = GetClubs("club3");

            Person p1 = new Person();
            p1.PersonName = "Person1";

            Person p2 = new Person();
            p2.PersonName = "Person2";

            List<Club> clubsForPerson1 = new List<Club>();
            clubsForPerson1.Add(club1);
            clubsForPerson1.Add(club3);

            List<Club> clubsForPerson2 = new List<Club>();
            clubsForPerson2.Add(club2);
            clubsForPerson2.Add(club3);

            p1.Clubs = clubsForPerson1;
            p2.Clubs = clubsForPerson2;

            db.Persons.Add(p1);
            db.Persons.Add(p2);

            int recordsAffected = db.SaveChanges();


        }
    }
```

Domain

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Club> Clubs { get; set; }
}

public class Club
{
    public int ClubId { get; set; }
    public string ClubName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Members { get; set; }
}

//System.Data.Entity.DbContext is from EntityFramework.dll
public class NerdDinners : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{

    public NerdDinners(string connString): base(connString)
    { 

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelbuilder)
    {
         //Fluent API - Plural Removal
        modelbuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Club> Clubs { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: @podiluska. No, I ran it only once.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that you create more contexts.

First you create the clubs. It's ok. But when you create the persons, you fetch the clubs via `GetClubs`, but for each club you dispose the actual entity framework context so you end up with detached entities. At `InsertPersons` you add detached club entities to the new persons so the actual context will think that the clubs are new clubs.

So when you add a club to a person you actually create new clubs.

This is because entity framework tracks the changes and manages the entities per context. If you add an entity to a context which does not contains it yet then it will treat like a new entity.

Actually, you should do something like this (not tested):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Database.SetInitializer<NerdDinners>(new MyInitializer());

    string connectionstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NerdDinners;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
    using (var db = new NerdDinners(connectionstring))
    {
        CreateClubs(db);
        InsertPersons(db);
    }

}

public static void CreateClubs(NerdDinners db)
{
    Club club1 = new Club();
    club1.ClubName = "club1";

    Club club2 = new Club();
    club2.ClubName = "club2";

    Club club3 = new Club();
    club3.ClubName = "club3";

    db.Clubs.Add(club1);
    db.Clubs.Add(club2);
    db.Clubs.Add(club3);

    int recordsAffected = db.SaveChanges();
}

public static Club GetClubs(string clubName, NerdDinners db)
{
    //var query = db.Clubs.Where(p => p.ClubName == clubName);
    var query = db.Clubs.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ClubName == clubName);
    return query;
}

public static void InsertPersons(NerdDinners db)
{
    Club club1 = GetClubs("club1", db);
    Club club2 = GetClubs("club2", db);
    Club club3 = GetClubs("club3", db);

    Person p1 = new Person();
    p1.PersonName = "Person1";

    Person p2 = new Person();
    p2.PersonName = "Person2";

    List<Club> clubsForPerson1 = new List<Club>();
    clubsForPerson1.Add(club1);
    clubsForPerson1.Add(club3);

    List<Club> clubsForPerson2 = new List<Club>();
    clubsForPerson2.Add(club2);
    clubsForPerson2.Add(club3);

    p1.Clubs = clubsForPerson1;
    p2.Clubs = clubsForPerson2;

    db.Persons.Add(p1);
    db.Persons.Add(p2);

    int recordsAffected = db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Of course you should refactor the structure of this code, but please notice that I use only one EF context for my operations.

Comment: In that code sample, there is only one EF context. I need separate EF contexts. Any thoughts?

Comment: if you want to use the entities from different source than the actual context then you need to attach them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PeterPorfy

Also read  [Exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648504/exception-of-type-system-objectdisposedexception/11663686#11663686)

I used

```
 ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Attach((IEntityWithKey)entity);
```

for attaching the objects from previous context.

One example for IEntityWithKey I used is as follows. Please comment if you see any issue with this approach.

```
public class Person : IEntityWithKey
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }

    public EntityKey EntityKey { get; set; }
}
```

Please refer the following also

1. [Problem with SaveChanges() Entity Framework 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693571/problem-with-savechanges-entity-framework-4-1)
2. [Entity Framework Updating Many-To-Many Relationships - POCO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275699/entity-framework-updating-many-to-many-relationships-poco)

---

Comment: For those who downvote - I am interested to see why there is a downvote. Is there something wrong with this answer?

Comment: I guess they prefer Peter's answer to be marked as the correct one. Just saying.