# EF Core Many To Many Problem when adding new Data (Duplicate Key Error)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two classes with a M:N Relation. For Example:

```
class User 
{
    int Id
    string Name

    ICollection<Addresses> Adresses
}

class Address 
{
    int Id
    string Text

    ICollection<User> Users
}
```

Everything went fine so far. EF created automatically a `N:M` table in my database. `UserAddress` with 2 columns (`UserId` and `AddressId`).

When I insert data manually with SQL - the output of EF Core is fine. I get all my data. But now I have a problem with inserting from my app:

I create a new `User` and want to add an existing address.

```
List<Address> ListOfAdresses = ... //(from DB)!
var y = ListOfAdresses.First();

var x = new User();
x.Addresses.Add(y);
```

and now when I want to add this to the `DBContext` and save I get an error.

He tries to create a new address... I get the error

> Duplicate Key Error.

How can I prevent this? I don't want him to add a new address. I want him to take the existing address from the db.

Answer (score 1):

There could be few things you should be aware of since I cannot explicitly review if they are right:

1. Check if you are using same context which basically serves as bridge to DB and if you have multiple contexts you cold end up with similar errors ([Entity Framework: Duplicate Records in Many-to-Many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646299/entity-framework-duplicate-records-in-many-to-many-relationship))
2. Check if your addresses are tracked by ChangeTracker. If your child entity in relation is fetched **AsNoTracking**, it will  do the work if you do updates only on parent entity in relation. But point at it will error will be when you try to update non-tracked entity, which is then interpreted as new, more precisely **EntityState.Added** because after fetching from DB it was not tracked. Long story short, check if your entity has modified state.

PS. Regarding **joining table**, it should be generated by ef conventions so it shouldnt do any problems (https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
List<Address> ListOfAdresses = ... //(from DB)!
var y = ListOfAdresses.First();

var x = new User();
x.Addresses.Add(y);
```

in the data access code:

```
dbContext.Users.Add(x);

//Just add addition code here before SaveChanges
dbContext.Entry(y).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

When `DbSet.Add` method is invoked, Ef core set EntryState of `y` to `Add` by default. When `SaveChanges` method is invoked, Ef core will try to insert the `y` into db, this caused the duplicate key exception thrown.

Just mark entry state of `y` to `Unchanged`, Ef core will only add the relationship between `x` and `y` to `UserAddress` table, and avoid to insert `y` into `Address` table,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, u need to check your entity relations.
I think, u can try to use x.AddressesId instead of x.Addresses.Add(y).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a table to define the connection between the address and the user. You need a third table UserAddress {
int Id
int UserId
int AddressId
}

Your tables should look like following for a many to many

User {
int Id
ICollection Address - this is a virtual property
}

these records should be unique otherwise you are storing duplicates
UserAddress {
int UserId - the id of the user
int AddressId - the address you are connecting them too
}

Address {
int Id
string Text
}

When you call the save it should first persist the address then it will take the id of the newly stored address and the id of the user and save the link to the UserAddress table.

Comment: this is not true anymore. with ef core 5 you can do it without: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea not to depend on EF, but create the third table yourself

```
public  class UserAddress 
{
UserId 
AddressId
virtural User User
virtual Address Address
}
```

in this case you can  always add new user and existing address

```
var userAddress= new UserAddress { User= new User {..}, AddressId=addressId};
context.UserAddresses.Add(userAddress);
context.SaveChanges();
```

or  connect existing items

```
var userAddress= new UserAddress { UserId= userId, AddressId=addressId};
```

Answer (score 0):

to perform m:m relation you need to create a table in between, so next example may help you:

- create m:m Model

```
public class UserAdress
{
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }        
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

- link your Models to m:m table

```
public class User 
{
    public int Id { set; get;}
    public string Name { set; get;}
    public virtual ICollection<UserAdress> UserAdresses { set; get;}
}
```

```
public class Address 
{
    public int Id { set; get;}
    public string Text { set; get;}
    public virtual ICollection<UserAdress> UserAdresses { set; get;}
}
```

- finally use Fluent API in your DbContext

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserAddresses>()
                .HasKey(pc => new { pc.UserId, pc.AddressId});

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserAddresses>()
                .HasOne(pc => pc.User)
                .WithMany(p => p.UserAddresses)
                .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.UserId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserAddresses>()
                .HasOne(pc => pc.Address)
                .WithMany(c => c.UserAddresses)
                .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.AddressId);
        }
```

Comment: this is not true anymore. with ef core 5 you can do it without: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#many-to-many

Comment: yes you are right ;) , depends if he use ef core 5, and this way still working perfectly